# How to install glibc to compile perf for android

Tags: android, c++, c, glibc, perf

when i compile perf for android, i recieve the error:

> *** No gnu/libc-version.h found, please install glibc-dev[el]/glibc-static

I tried to install libc6-dev and build-essential but i still met this error. After that i compile and install glibc follow the instruction:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Glibc2-HOWTO-5.html

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/

However, i have some problems with this way, so glibc is successfully installed.
Do you have any ideas to solve that errors or install glibc-dev as suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at external/linux-tools-perf/ inside android sources?

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/linux-tools-perf/

Comment: yes, i want to compile linux tool perf for android. Have you done this work?

Comment: I built external/linux-tools-perf/ along with whole android repository. Is that what you want help in?

Because external/linux-tools-perf/ already has things like bionic linked to it so you don't have to worry about libc.

Comment: I built external/linux-tools-perf with cross compile on ubuntu 12.04 but i received errors *No gnu/libc-version.h found, please install glibc-dev[el]/glibc-static*. But my gnu/libc-version.h is available in urs/include/gnu/libc-version.h. What's wrong with my steps, which follow the page:
http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/linux/tools/perf/Documentation/android.txt
Can you help me with your instruction? You can send it to my email trinhhiepth@gmail.com. Many thanks

Comment: I think external/linux-tools-perf/ gets built when you build the whole android tree. You don't have to build it separately.

Comment: @Miline did you compile perf for android using a cross compiler ?? i tried hard and failed, did you find a workarround ?

Answer (score -1):

I spent hours trying to get perf tools compiled for ARM. Tried all the methods mentioned in https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/linux/tools/perf/Documentation/android.txt
They never worked for some reason. Finally I stumbled upon this:
https://wiki.linaro.org/LMG/Engineering/UsingPerfOnAndroid

MAKE NOTE OF THE TYPO in the page: It should be "m -j32 perf"
I actually went with "m -j16 perf"
Works for me! Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you include in your answer specifically what needs to be done to correct the problem? Sometimes links go bad.